# вывод строки в си вертикально (повернуть на 90 градусов)

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток. Есть задача выводить подписи на графиках вертикально. Используя только возможности языка Си. Я так понял что стандартный вывод строки или символа не позволяет повернуть на 90 градусов. Придется рисовать символ. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким?
Нашел реализацию отрисовки символа по пиксельно но классически горизонтально. Не могу догадаться как преобразовать координаты X и Y для вывода того же символа но вертикально?
Алгоритм вывода примерно такой.

```
     for (TempByte0000= 0x00; TempByte0000 < Шрифты_Шрифт[КодШрифта].ЗаголовокШрифта.ВысотаСимвола; TempByte0000++)
  for (TempByte0001= 0x00; TempByte0001 < Шрифты_Шрифт[КодШрифта].ЗаголовокШрифта.ШиринаСимвола; TempByte0001++)
   {
     Видео_УстановитьПиксель(ПозицияX + TempByte0001, ПозицияY + TempByte0000, Цвет0000);
   }
```

Comment: Я бы поискал уже развернутые фонты и отрисовывал  ими.

Comment: _Используя только возможности языка C_, у вас нет средств выводить графику. Так что рассказывайте, каким графическим фреймворком вы пользуетесь.

Answer (score 1):

По идее так:

```
НоваяПозицияX = ПозицияY;
НоваяПозицияY = -ПозицияX;
```

Это будет поворот по часовой.

```
НоваяПозицияX = -ПозицияY;
НоваяПозицияY = ПозицияX;
```

Это против часовой.

Comment: у меня область не разбита на четверти. у меня одна область где X:0-800  Y: 0-600. Где то будет располагаться символ например в месте 300х300, он отрисовался  горизонтально. если я сделаю НоваяПозицияY = -ПозицияX; то уйду за координатную отсь. как мне это сделать в пределах моей области 800х600?

Comment: Рисуешь в (0,0), после вычисления очередной координаты сдвигаешь ее на место отрисовки. Например вычислил что надо нарисовать в (1,5), теперь сдвигаешь в (1+300,5+300). И так каждую точку.